# US visa application : Kids passport has different mother’s name in passport as compared to Mother’s name in her passport

Tags: india, us-visa

My wife’s passport has her name as Ruchi Dua.
Kids’ passport has mother’s name as Ruchi Dua Chaudhary.

Will this cause a problem when applying for US visa for kids ?

Comment: Will the visa applications be submitted and processed in India?

Comment: Yes. Visa to be applied at Us embassy in India

Answer (score 5):

I have no personal experience with this, but given the frequency with which we see name discrepancies such as this, that is to say, relatively minor discrepancies, forming the basis of questions from Indian citizens, I imagine that visa processors in India must encounter them on a regular basis.  There is no requirement in US law for your child's passport to mention your wife's name, so the fact that it is there is only extra information as far as the US is concerned.  If the names were very different, it might trigger some concern, for example about the possibility of international child abduction, but with the names given in this question it's very unlikely to pose any sort of problem.